# PowerBI issue with visuals, asTimeline and a Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have asTimeline visual and below a Table. The idea is to display in the Table a Link to the specified record in another system. The problem is that I would like to show this Table only when there is exactly 1 record selected in asTimeline. Generally, the filtering works fine, but the table should be shown when there is only 1 element in it, and hidden otherwise.

Currently it is something like this:

[image]
[image]

Now, I have tried using the solution with a Transparent measure, similar to [this](https://insights.votivasoft.com/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/). Tbe problem is that it doesn't work, the background of the table visual doesn't change when changing the selection (it is not a color problem, I have tried others). The question is whether the ISFILTERED is triggered at all when changing the selection?
Currently I have Make Transparent measure defined as

```
Make Transparent = IF(ISFILTERED(Table[Id]), "Red", "Blue")
```

and in asTimeline I have column *Id* specified as Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different idea about how to achieve that, It does not hide objects but uses a measure that returns values only when there is only one value selected.

```
Link = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[link],BLANK())
or
Link = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[link],"Please select only one Id")

A different formula might be
Link = IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[Id]), SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Link]), BLANK() )
```

Put one of those measures in a table, alone, and you should achieve what you need (also format the measure as "web URL").

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have created a measure Link2 = SELECTEDVALUE(DeploymentsTable[Link], BLANK()), in table Values I have only Link2, and the result is that there is always link displayed in the table, whether there is bar selected or deselected.

Comment: That's strange but means that there is only one value selected even without any selection on the Id. I will add another formula in the answer which uses HASONEVALUE().... even if I don't expect it to behave differently